Artin's theorem exercise - proving that the fixed field is generated by the coefficients of the minimal polynomial
Suppose $L/K$ is a finite extension. $G$ is a finite group of $K$-automorphisms of $L$. Denote by $L^G$ the field elements of $L$ fixed by action of $G$. For any $\alpha \in L$ we write $f(t, \alpha) = \prod_{g \in G} (t-g(\alpha))$.
Suppose $L = K(\alpha)$. I want to prove that $L^G$ is generated over $K$ by the coefficients of $f$.
Here are some of my thoughts.
Note that the degree of this polynomial is $\# G$. Let $K(c_1,...,c_{\#G})$ be the field $K$ adjoin the coefficients of the polynomial. All of those coefficients lie inside $L^G$ (as the polynomial lies in $L^G[X]$ by construction), meaning that $K(c_1,...,c_{\#G}) \subseteq L^G$. We know $[L : L^G] = \# G$ from Artin's theorem.
I want to now either:

Establish the reverse inclusion, and show $K(c_1,...,c_{\#G}) \supseteq L^G$, which will give me $K(c_1,...,c_{\#G}) = L^G$.

Show that the degree $[L^G : K(c_1,...,c_{\# G})$ is $1$, which will also give me $K(c_1,...,c_{\#G}) = L^G$.


I am unsure how to proceed down either of these routes and would appreciate some guidance.

Can you show that any element of $L^G$ is a symmetric function of the $g(\alpha)$'s?

@blargoner how would this be done?

Let $K’$ be the field generated by $K$ and the coefficients of $f$. Then $L=K’(\alpha)$ so $[L:K’]$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Now show that $[L:K’]\leq\mathrm{deg}(f)$.
